# migrate from jack to native Java 8

Tags: java, android, java-stream, android-jack-and-jill

I'm trying to use lambda expressions and streams in my Android project.I'm using [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) library for streams, and native Java 8 for lambda expressions. To be able to use Java 8 features I need to add

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

this code in my gradle, but the compiler shows this error:

```
Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.
```

and then I added this

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

and there was no error by the compiler, but **on runtime the same error keeps showing.**
This is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "home.gio.calorieplanner"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.thoughtbot:expandablecheckrecyclerview:1.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    compile 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport:1.5.4'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is the method where I'm using lambda expressions and streams.

```
public String identifySubMenu(String group, int index) {
    List<Product> prod = StreamSupport
            .stream(Main.outRetailChainList.get(Constants.GOODWILL).getProducts())
            .filter(item -> item.getCategory().equals(group))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return prod.get(index).getSubMenu();
}
```

So my question is how can I fix this error.

Comment: Please show the stacktrace that you get at runtime.

Comment: @Stefan read the question... `Error:Jack is required`

Comment: @cricket_007 Sure, I've read that. To me `Error:Jack is required` very much looks like a compile-time message. Are you sure that this is a runtime error message?

Comment: this error is compile-time if I dont have jack enabled, but if I enable jack in gradle, than it's runtime. also on compile-time error is written twice, I dont know why. Like this https://prnt.sc/f9qg6y .
This is stack trace displayed during runtime error: https://codepaste.net/o7nsip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have many options :

1 - upgrade your version of android studio to 3.0
this versions don't need jack anymore and lambda are now correctly handled, but this version is in canary channel, that is their "beta" one.

2 - don't use lambda now and wait 3.0 to be released as jack don't handle lambda fully correctly. You got a fully explained page on this : https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

3 - use a plugin named [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda), but this increase your compilation time. To my mind, this option is way too heavy just for lambda

Comment: Retrolambda works well before build tools 3.0, and it won't work with 3.0+

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Could you provide any pointers (hints, links ...) what the retrolambda problems are with AS 3.0?

Comment: @StefanZobel they write somewhere that the build tools support lambda out of the box, but it doesn't work with THE android-apt plugin nor Retrolambda.